# discordbot commands not working, no errors in code or terminal (help)

Tags: javascript, discord

hey guys i need help with my code. I watched a series of CodeLyons videos on youtube to code my own discord bot, theres no errors in my code or terminal now but none of my commands are working and i need help fixing it, here is my code https://srcb.in/AIoi76qhnw

Comment: Welcome!, First of all, please do not link us to another webpage for showing your code, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in the question instead, because it will be hard for us dig through the whole code to find the problem. Second, Add more details to the question instead of `its not working`, include details like "how is it not working" and add more informations necessary for the question. Lastly, the introduction stating `hey guys...` is not necessary therefore should be removed because questions should be summarized.

Comment: And also: New users are recommended to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback.

Comment: I have no knowledge of `discord.js` but should it be `if(command) command.execute(message, args)`?